# How to write $\sigma \in S_k$ as a composite of elementary permutations?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\sigma = (135) \in S_6$. We know that $\sigma$ can be written as transpositions, or 2-cycles, as

$$(135)=(15)(13)$$

How do I write it as composite of elementary permutations? The definition of elementary permutation is the following

> Let $1\le i < k$. Let $e_i$ be an element in $S_k$ such that $e_i (i) = i+1$ and $e_i (i+1) = i$. We call $e_i$ and **elementary permutation**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $(135) = (15)(13)$.

Now, note that $(13) = (12)(23)(12)$ because $1 \to 2 \to 3$, $2 \to 1 \to 2$, $3 \to 2 \to 1$.

Furthermore, $(15) = (16)(65)(16)$, because $1 \to 6 \to 5$, $ 6 \to 1 \to 6$, $5 \to 6 \to 1$.

Finally, $(15)(13) = (16)(65)(16)(12)(23)(12)$, where each permutation is elementary (this depends on your definition of elementary, but I feel you should include $(16)$ in your definition, for symmetry, because at the moment it is not there).

Suppose you are not including $(16)$ as an elementary permutation, then you have to work by the following manner: $(15) = (12)(23)(34)(45)(34)(23)(12)$, hence $(15)(13) = (12)(23)(34)(45)(34)(23)(12)(12)(23)(12) = (12)(23)(34)(45)(34)(12)$.

Hence, you can rework your answer  whichever way your definition operates.

Answer (score 0):

For the transpositions $(i\ j)$, one can easily verify that
$$\begin{split}
 &(i\ j)\\
=&(i\ i+1)(i+1\ i+2)\cdots(j-1\ j)(j-2\ j-1)(j-3\ j-2)\cdots(i+1\ i+2)(i\ i+1).
\end{split}$$
Thus the example you giving can be written as follows,
$$
\begin{split}
(135)&=(15)(13)\\
&=(12)(23)(34)(45)(34)(23)(12)(12)(23)(12)\\&=(12)(23)(34)(45)(34)(12).
\end{split}
$$